# How do i implement 'INSERT' using PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Using PHP's PDO and prepared statements, how do I implement the following?

```
$sql = 'insert into $tablename ($var1, $var2, $var3, ...) VALUES (:placeholder1, :placeholder2, ...)';
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean that you want to insert into a dynamically chosen table with dynamically chosen columns, you must build the table and columns by concatenating variables together. You can't use placeholders for those (though you can use them in the `VALUES`).  It is recommended to check against a whitelist of possible table names.

Comment: @Michael Checklists or Reflection API or ORMs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO '.$tablename.' ('.implode(',', array_keys($inserting)).') VALUES ('.str_pad('', count($inserting)*2-1, '?,').')');
$sth->execute(array_values($inserting));
```

Where `$tablename` is the name of the table and `$inserting` is an associative array with keys being the names of the columns and the values of the array being the values to insert.